# Problem decrypting a file I encrypted using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, encryption, aes

I wanted a pair of functions, one in PowerShell to encrypt a file and another in .NET to decrypt the file.

With some help from Google Bard I have generated the PowerShell script below to encrypt a file. This is working as expected and a file is produced.

```
function Protect-File {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$FileName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
        [string]$KeyAsPlainText
    )

    $Algorithm = 'AES'
    $CipherMode = 'CBC'
    $PaddingMode = 'PKCS7'

    try {
        $Crypto = [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm]::Create($Algorithm)
        $Crypto.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($KeyAsPlainText)
        $Crypto.GenerateIV() 
   
        $Crypto.Mode = $CipherMode
        $Crypto.Padding = $PaddingMode

        $DestinationFile = $FileName + ".encrypted"

        $Transform = $Crypto.CreateEncryptor()
        $CryptoStream = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(
            [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($DestinationFile),
            $Transform,
            [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode]::Write
        )

        try {
            try {
                $FileStreamReader = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($FileName)
                $FileStreamReader.CopyTo($CryptoStream)
            } finally {
                $FileStreamReader.Close()
            }
        } finally {
            $CryptoStream.Close()
        }

        # Write IV to the beginning of the encrypted file
        $FileStreamWriter = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($DestinationFile)
        $FileStreamWriter.Seek(0, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin)
        $FileStreamWriter.Write($Crypto.IV, 0, $Crypto.IV.Length)
        $FileStreamWriter.Close()

        Write-Output "File encrypted successfully: $DestinationFile"
    } catch {
        Write-Error $_
    }
}

Protect-File -Filename "D:\Temp\temp.txt" -KeyAsPlainText "r4EoMu6hxWHlsFgizGf3L2WIEJwwVFIUrADdCU4U9xA="
```

I then created the following function in .NET 4.8 to decrypt the file:

```
public static bool UnprotectFile(string sourceFile, string destinationFile, string keyAsPlainText)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] encryptionKey = Convert.FromBase64String(keyAsPlainText);

                // Read IV from the beginning of the encrypted file
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
                {
                    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                    fileStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);

                    // Configure encryption algorithm
                    Aes crypto = Aes.Create();
                    crypto.Key = encryptionKey;
                    crypto.IV = iv;
                    crypto.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    crypto.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                    // Decrypt the file
                    using (ICryptoTransform transform = crypto.CreateDecryptor())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
                            File.OpenWrite(destinationFile),
                            transform,
                            CryptoStreamMode.Write
                        ))
                        {
                            using (FileStream fileStreamReader = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
                            {
                                fileStreamReader.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                } //catch block removed
```

The function to decrypt the file is failing when closing the CryptoStream with the exception:
*System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The input data is not a complete block.'*

Does anyone have any insights on what may be causing this exception?

Comment: It looks as if in the PowerShell script the first block (=first 16 bytes) of the ciphertext is overwritten with the IV. In addition, in the C# code the IV (the first 16 bytes) must not be copied to the CryptoStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code, the first issue is in your PowerShell function `Protect-File`, you're **overwriting** the first 16 bytes on `$FileStreamWriter.Write($Crypto.IV, 0, $Crypto.IV.Length)`. You should first write the `IV` and then `$FileStreamReader.CopyTo($CryptoStream)`.

In summary, how your PowerShell function should look:

```bash
function Protect-File {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string] $FileName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string] $KeyAsPlainText
    )
    
    # these 3 could be parameters
    $Algorithm = 'AES'
    $CipherMode = 'CBC'
    $PaddingMode = 'PKCS7'

    try {
        $Crypto = [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm]::Create($Algorithm)
        $Crypto.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($KeyAsPlainText)
        $Crypto.GenerateIV()

        $Crypto.Mode = $CipherMode
        $Crypto.Padding = $PaddingMode

        $DestinationFile = $FileName + '.encrypted'

        # Write the IV first
        $FileStreamWriter = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($DestinationFile)
        $FileStreamWriter.Write($Crypto.IV, 0, $Crypto.IV.Length)
        $FileStreamWriter.Flush()

        # No need to re-open the stream, can be passed in as argument
        $Transform = $Crypto.CreateEncryptor()
        $CryptoStream = [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream]::new(
            $FileStreamWriter,
            $Transform,
            [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode]::Write)

        $FileStreamReader = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($FileName)
        $FileStreamReader.CopyTo($CryptoStream)
        Write-Output "File encrypted successfully: $DestinationFile"
    }
    finally {
        if ($FileStreamReader) {
            $FileStreamReader.Dispose()
        }
        if ($CryptoStream) {
            $CryptoStream.Dispose()
        }
        if ($FileStreamWriter) {
            $FileStreamWriter.Dispose()
        }
    }
}
```

Then for your C# method, which as you have it will work for unprotecting the file, however **the first 16 bytes should be skipped**. Skipping the first 16 bytes is done when `fileStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);` so, **you should re-use this stream** instead of opening a new one: `using (FileStream fileStreamReader = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))`.

In summary:

```cs
public static bool UnprotectFile(
    string sourceFile,
    string destinationFile,
    string keyAsPlainText)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] encryptionKey = Convert.FromBase64String(keyAsPlainText);

        // Read IV from the beginning of the encrypted file
        using (Aes crypto = Aes.Create())
        using (FileStream sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFile))
        using (FileStream destinationStream = File.OpenWrite(destinationFile))
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            sourceStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);

            // Configure encryption algorithm
            crypto.Key = encryptionKey;
            crypto.IV = iv;
            crypto.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            crypto.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Decrypt the file
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
                destinationStream,
                crypto.CreateDecryptor(),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                sourceStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        // handling...
        return false;
    }
}
```